# How to set empty image for HTML 5 <picture>?

Tags: html, image, responsive-design

My website has an image on top that I want to completely remove on small screen sizes. The HTML 5 `<picture>` allows to change images based on screen size but it does not work when I set an empty URL (the image is still always shown):

```
    <picture>
        <source media="(max-height: 650px)" srcset="">
        <img src="img/top.jpg"/>
    </picture>
```

If I set an nonempty but invalid URL, I get an image place holder instead.

How can I achieve a complete removal of the image?

Comment: Just a question, why use `picture` element which has [bad browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture)?

Comment: @Vucko Because it is a hobby project not work, in this case I always opt for the newest features and ignore the harsh realties of real world browsers :-)

Comment: by using CSS Media query you can remove the image completely. for example @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {display:none;} it will work i guess

Comment: What happens if you give the `srcset` a value, but leave the `fallback` image empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the width size of the device in **(max-width: 1500px)** which you want to remove the image completely. For your understanding i have given 1500px.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  picture {display:none;}
}
```

```html
   <picture>
        <source media="(max-height: 650px)" srcset="">
        <img src="img/top.jpg"/>
    </picture>
```

Comment: Ah I didn't know media queries yet, this is even easier, thanks!